# How to get top and left of jquery element with paddings

Tags: jquery, html, css

initially tried to

```
var t = parseInt(el.offset().top);
var l = parseInt(el.offset().left);

var tp = parseInt(el.css('padding-top'));
var lp = parseInt(el.css('padding-left'));
```

and use

```
t - tp, l - lp
```

but somehow t return top WITH padding and l is less than left without padding

Edit: may be this is related to the display of the element which is list-view

Comment: What is `_this` ? `#id` or `.classname`? If it is an `id` or `classname` why haven't you `""` quoted them like so => `"_this"`?

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery's` `position()` method?

Comment: $(_this) is the required jquery element in this context

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(this)`?

Comment: no, it was created manually (updated question)

Comment: Paste the relevant `HTML` here or create a `jsfiddle` so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get Top Left using [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
var a=parseInt($("#a").css("top"));
var a1=parseInt($("#a").css("left"));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="a"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#a
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
top:25px;
padding-top:50px;
left:25px;
padding-left:50px;

}
```